# Knapsack Algorithm using decimal values?

Tags: algorithm

Please, can someone point me in a right direction?   I am looking for a variant of a knapsack algorithm that uses decimal values.   Specifically: I working with financial values (decimals) to answer a question:  Which decimal values from a list sum to a specific decimal value.

Thank you very much for help/direction.

Comment: All the logic for integers applies to decimals. Just consider the integers to be cents.

Comment: Actually it would seem to be somewhat different. At least it's complexity is quite different, so I wouldn't say it's just a matter of plugging the decimals into the integer formula.

Comment: Please clarify, are the item values decimal or the decision variables? You now have answers for both (one is gene's comment), but they're fundamentally different and you should choose the right one.

Comment: Example is the best:  Parameter 1 = list(10.50 , 2.75 , 3.00, 4.10, 5.90, 100.00, 9.99)  Parameter 2 = capacity = 16.84.   I need to find items in the list that make up the capacity exactly.  (aka, i need to find values 2.75, 4.10, and 9.99 -- they add up to 16.84)

Comment: In the example above,  weights = profits (if using knapsack).  Also fractions cannot be used.

Comment: ok then it is not continuous knapsack, but you can use Gene's trick

Comment: Ok, so I found that the logic that applies to integers is not the same as decimals.  Since I am using always only 2 decimal places I can convert the decimal to integer by multiplying by 100, then use the integer logic.  However the size of the array/matrix explodes -- working with financial decimal values as big as $10,000,000.50 as an example.   So I continue to be interested to know if there is another way/another algorithm.  Thank you all for your feedback.

Comment: ah cool. so if im using a cash value for my weights i can just use the cents, pennys in integer format. thanks very much!

Answer (score -1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_knapsack_problem

No need for dynamic programming here, a greedy algorithm will work: just sort the items by their value/weight ratio

Comment: Looking at my Algorithms textbook, is the continuous knapsack problem the same as the greedy method for knapsack problem?

Comment: Problem and algorithm are two different things. But yes I am referring to that one

Comment: Since I need to find the exact answer -- the knapsack must be filled up to the capacity -- no fraction allowed,  I cannot use continuous/greedy Knapsack.  If the greedy result does not fill the knapsack to capacity, the algorithm has to keep trying util the combination of items that fills the knapsack is found.